# C++ testing private callback methods

Tags: c++, testing, callback, googletest

I have a class, which registers private methods of itself with other classes to be used as callbacks. This utilises `std::bind` to create an `std::function` that points to the private method.

Example: (names are not actual class names)

```
class DataProcessor {
private:
    void callback() {
        // Do something
    };
public:
    DataProcessor(IDataSupplier* supplier) {
        supplier->subscribe(std::bind(&DataProcessor::callback, this));
    };
};
```

Now I want to verify that the callback function performs the correct actions. I use gtest for my tests, and create a mock of `IDataSupplier` with gmock to create this object with.

I can't call `DataProcessor::callback()` directly, since it is private when viewed from the test. I would prefer not to change `DataProcessor` for my test.

Normally, the callback is accessible because `IDataSupplier` has access to the `std::function` object that wraps the private method. Because I have a mocked version of `IDataSupplier`, I don't think I'm able to capture the callback that was given to it (and again, it feels wrong to have to rely on this; what if gmock stops allowing me to get the provided `std::function`?)

So my questions boil down to these two:

1. Am I doing A Bad Thing (tm) by trying to test a private callback method?
2. How should I approach testing this callback, if I should do it at all?

Comment: It was a typo, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

With a fresh mind in the morning I figured out the answer:

With gmock, you can define a function that should be called if your mocked function is called. This allowed me to receive the callback passed to the subscribe function, and thus store the callback for usage in the test. Following the example above:

```
using ::testing::_;

class UnitTests_DataProcessor : public ::testing::Test {
  std::function<void()> m_dataCallback;
  MockDataSupplier m_dataSupplier;

  std::unique_ptr<DataProcessor> m_dataProcessor;

  void SetUp() override {
    ON_CALL(m_dataSupplier, subscribe(_))
      .WillOnce([this](std::function<void()> callback) { m_dataCallback = callback; });

    m_dataProcessor = std::make_unique<DataProcessor>(m_dataSupplier);
  };
};

TEST_F(UnitTests_DataProcessor, TestCallback) {
  /*
   * Contains the bound callback function of the DataProcessor class, which is still
   * defined private but accessed through the same method as the production code would.
   */
  m_dataCallback();

  // ASSERTIONS
}
```